# Can't open phpmyadmin on browser with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose.yml file with the following parameters:

```
version: '3'
services:
 php:
  build: ./docker/images/php
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
   - ./htdocs:/var/www/html
  container_name: php
  networks:
   - default
 
 mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dani
   MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_database
   MYSQL_USER: dani
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: dani
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
   - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  networks:
   - default
 
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: phpmyadmin
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  environment:
   - PMA_HOST=mysql
  networks:
   - default
      
networks:
 default:
```

This is the console output:
[image]

But, when I try to go to localhost:8080 :

[image]I can't see phpmyadmin dashboard. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can change for image and port by this code:

```
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin:latest
  container_name: phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 8080:80
  environment:
   - PMA_HOST=mysql
  networks:
   - default
```

May be just it for your problem, good luck

Comment: You're right! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the wrong port in the phpmyadmin service, you've to map from 8080 to 80 where the application && try this environement also

Change the port & Env with this one:

```
ports:
  - 8080:80
environment:
  - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Try in your image

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - mysql_network
```